Pip install failing on pip >22.2.2 when installing packages from PyPi via proxy, but not from PyPi directly
UPDATE
After further study, I found that I have grossly misunderstood the problem I'm encountering, and have re-written the question to reflect the correct, up-to-date details.
================
I am trying to install a Python package on a local machine that does not have direct access to the internet due to security reasons. In the past, we have done our installations via a proxy rest API with full internet access that copies across the packages from PyPI.
It has become quite apparent in recent months that the process is no longer compatible with recent versions of pip. Running pip install via the proxy returns the following error:
$ pip install --trusted-host url-to-proxy.com --index-url http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi --extra-index-url http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi package-name[optional-dependencies]

Looking in indexes: http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi, http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi
Collecting package-name[optional-dependencies]
  Obtaining dependency information for package-name[optional-dependencies] from http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi/package-name/package-name-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
$  ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi/package-name/package-name-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
$ ERROR: 404 Client Error: Not Found for http://url-to-proxy.com:8000/pypi/package-name/package-name-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata

When I try and run the same installation of the package using the URL from PyPi, it works without issue:
$ pip install --trusted-host https://pypi.org/simple/ --index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ package-name[optional-dependencies]

The package.tar.gz and package-py3-none-any.whl files on the proxy appear to be identical to those on PyPI, and comparing the contents yields no noticeable differences. pip v22.2.2 is the highest version for which this installation via proxy completes without issue, so the URLs should be correct.
This leads me to believe that something must have changed from pip v22.2.2 to pip v22.3 that breaks its ability to communicate with the proxy properly to get the .whl.metadata needed.
What might have changed, and how might I make the process compatible with newer versions of pip? Thanks!

Does your private repository also have the whl.metadata? The 404 seems to be coming from that URL.

Hey, thanks for following up on this question! Where would the .whl metadata be stored in a repository? I've tried opening the .whl files in both the private and PyPi repositories, and they both appear identical. There is a METADATA file within.

To be honest, I don't know. My private repository with pypiserver does not have them, and I am presently unable to access my devpi server. I suspect this is the root of your problem, though : https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/8254 , which suggests there's to be a new metadata file next to the package itself, not inside it. There's been a fair bit of churn in the python packaging ecosystem. I expect I'm going to have to deal with this soon as well, so thanks for the heads up :P

Also, the http error suggests a separate file is being looked for. PyPI servers are and have always (or atleast as far as I've known them) been simple static http servers or compatible with them, as far as pip is concerned. The http request wouldn't be able to look inside the whl for a specific file contained within.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0658/

Hey @ChintalagiriShashank, thank you so much for your efforts to shed light on this situation. I have since discussed this matter with the authors of the code, and realise that I have fundamentally misunderstood the architecture of this setup. I should have amended my question with the up-to--date context by the time you see this!
